# Check if the patches are applied in magento?

Tags: php, security, magento, patch

I have applied patch 6788 in Magento 1.9.2.1.

I have applied it by copy-pasting the files and folders and cleared the cache after applying the patch. When I check my site in www.magereport.com still the patch status shows "unknown".

Also I don't see `applied.patches.list` in `app/etc/` folder.

If i install the patch through shell it shows this error

> "ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully ".

I don't know whats the real issue is.

Comment: Did you applied 6788 or 8788 security patch ?

Comment: If you apply the patch by copy pasting the files you will never get applied.patches.list file. Why don't you use sh command to apply the patch?

Comment: Did you check Patch 6788 is installed but MageReport disagrees? section of  https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/how-to-install-magento-patch-supee-6788/

Comment: i applied 6788 @pankaj pareek